# C# cast is not valid

Tags: c#, listview, exception

in my c# program I have a listview click event.Here is my code :

```
private void factorLV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
{
    if (listview1.SelectedItems.Count == 0)
        return;
    listview2.Items.Clear();
    listview2.Show();
    DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
    List<ReportFactorResult> list = db.ReportFactor(Convert.ToInt32(listview1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text)).ToList<ReportFactorResult>();
    foreach (ReportFactorResult val in list)
    {
        ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem((Convert.ToString(listview2.Items.Count + 1)).ToString());
        lst.SubItems.Add(val.storeName);
        lst.SubItems.Add(val.Code.ToString());
        lst.SubItems.Add(val.factorNumber.ToString());
        lst.SubItems.Add(val.salePrice.ToString());
        listview2.Items.Add(lst);
    }
}
  catch(Exception ex)
{
   messageBox.show(ex.message);
}
}
```

when I run the program in visual studio it works properly.But as I Run the .exe out of the visual studio environment it meets this exception :

> Specified cast is not valid

Image Below shows Exception without try catch. when I used try catch also I got "Specified cast..." message .

http://i59.tinypic.com/2qkl3qg.png

Also, in visual studio My program connected remotely to sql server management  but in outside visual studio I connected to Restored database in SQLExpress .

Comment: I guess outside visual studio you have different data and `Convert.ToInt32()` fails. I suppose in the selected item, subitem index 0 text is not a valid int.

Comment: Why ToString() two times? `(Convert.ToString(listview2.Items.Count + 1)).ToString()`

Comment: @GrantWinney:no because it is a windows exception.It only shows the function.

Comment: What does `ReportFactor` returns? I guess that's the prblem. Post the full error message.

Comment: conver.ToString() was just for test.we added it after exception occured.

Comment: @GrantWinney: "Specified cast is not valid" this is the exception occurres.It was obvious that this is the message of try catch.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel : it returns 3 int and an string . ReportFactor is a stored procedure in mySql.

Comment: Just paste the full stacktrace of the error. Its hard to help without it.

Comment: @GrantWinney : I tested the try catch in my main code,I just did not update the code here.The message box showed the exact message I told.

Comment: @Majid To avoid this confusion, it would be better to update your question instead. We are now looking at code that differs from yours. This makes helping you extremely difficult.

Comment: write a try catch around your shown code and show us the output of exception.ToString() please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have shown the stacktrace its more clear what your problem is.

Currently your problem is in mapping your sql fields to `ReportFactorResult`. In particular ReportFactorResult has an int64 field which has a different field type in your database.

For further help we would need to see `ReportFactorResult` and your DB scheme. But if you look into your `ReportFactorResult` class and search for all int64 fields there you may find the problematic field by yourself.